# GLFW simple triangle is lost?

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I modified the "[Simple example](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/master/examples/simple.c)" example in GLFW3.0.4 in Mac OSX 10.8 as an XCode 4.6 project (runs fine when unchanged). I am having a (2D) rectangle drawn with an external library (which draws via shaders). I can see the rectangle but If I draw the sample triangle (*immediate* drawn) before it, the triangle is seen in the first splash (frame) and then it is lost. If I try to draw it after, the triangle is never seen. I can only see the rectangle and I don't know what settings/states the library is changing!

I tried to inspect the application with [OpenGL Profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGLProfilerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Stopped before `CGLFlushDrawable` and could not find the triangle in any of the buffers (front, back, depth, stencil).

Am I doing something (prominently) wrong? The profiler allows only gl-function breakpoints. How can I debug this (more efficiently) and find the problem.

Here is (much of the changed parts of) the code:

```
void glfw2DViewport(GLFWwindow * window) {
    float ratio;
    int width, height;

    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    ratio = width / (float) height;

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0); // Lets see if something black is drawn!!
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    // eye is at 0,0,0 looking to positive Z, -1(behind) to 1 are clipping planes:
    //  https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml
    glOrtho(ratio, -ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.0f, -1.f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glLoadIdentity();

    // ----- 2D settings -----    

    glfwSwapInterval(1); 

    glEnable(GL_SMOOTH);       
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  
    //glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST); // Disabling changed nothing!!
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);     
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glLineWidth(5.0f);      
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glPointSize(5.0f);      
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH); 

}

int main(void) {        
    GLFWwindow* window;            
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);        
    glfw2DViewport(window);

    //...

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        //drawUnitTriangle(); // can be seen just in the first frame!

        glPushClientAttrib(GL_CLIENT_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS); // A vain attempt?
        glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS); // Another vain attempt??
        external_library_identity_matrix();
        external_library_rectangle(POS,RED);
        external_library_flush();
        glPopAttrib();
        glPopClientAttrib();

        // Other vain attempts:
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
        glLoadIdentity();

        drawUnitTriangle(); // Nothing is Drawn!!

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);        
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the posted code is exactly what you are building with?  If that's true, please check the argument of `glMatrixMode()` it should be `GL_MODELVIEW`, not `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX`. There are two places where you set it like this.

Since you already have `glfw2DViewport()`, why don't you put it in the `while` loop and delete other model view setting codes?

Comment: No, I skipped external library functions and `GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX` was a remnant of my (several) vain attempts; reverted back and nothing has changed. Starting the loop with `glfw2DViewport()` also did change nothing. External library functions change something so that other drawing functions do not work beyond that line, even if I encapsulate them between push-pop stuff...

Comment: Nothing changes even if I use `glfw2DViewport(window)` just before `drawUnitTriangle()`!?